# gdb commands gdbstub to write to _Unwind_DebugHook memory location

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, gdb, x86-64

I ported a gdbstub for an OS I'm working on which runs on x86_64. The host which is running gdb is connected to the target that has the stub and the OS over serial. I have an `int3` instruction in the source code to force the OS to jump into the stub's code which it does. The problem is if I try to step to the next instruction using `nexti` the stub stops responding and the host keeps timing out.

Looking at the packets that the host is sending I see this:

```
Sending packet: $Me1dc20,1:cc#6c...Ack
Timed out.
Timed out.
Timed out.
Ignoring packet error, continuing...
```

which means that the host is telling the stub to write `cc` (which is the opcode for `int3`) to memory location `0xe1dc20`. I looked into that memory location and found this:

`(gdb) x/16i 0xe1dc20`

```
   0xe1dc20 <_Unwind_DebugHook>: retq   
   0xe1dc21:    data16 nopw %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   0xe1dc2c:    nopl   0x0(%rax)
```

This function is part of gcc's code here https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libgcc/unwind-dw2.c but it is not used anywhere in the source file that I am debugging.

Now obviously it is causing me troubles so I disabled memory writing functionality in my stub so that it longer responds to memory writing commands `$M` and `$X` and when I did I was able to execute `nexti` and `step` in gdb without issues. The stub uses the `RFLAGS.TF` for flow control.

The question is why is gdb trying to set a breakpoint in a function that I am not using anywhere and how do I prevent it from doing so? I thought about adding an if statement in the stub to ignore writes to this memory location but is there a less intrusive way of doing it?

Comment: Does `stepi` work?  `nexti` can execute more than one instruction.  I found it odd that you mentioned `step` and `nexti`, but not problems with `stepi`, since `stepi` is the simplest most primitive functionality.  (Often done using `TF`.  `IF` is the interrupt-enable flag for external interrupts, and has no effect on taking an `int3` or not, or other synchronous traps.)   Also, `e1dc50` from the GDB command is a different address than `0xe1dc20  _Unwind_DebugHook`  (5 vs. 2 in the second-last digit of the address).

Comment: @PeterCordes I meant `TF` and `0xe1dc20`. Sorry I wrote this after hours of debugging. Just corrected them. I just tried `stepi` and yes it does work and does not send write commands to that memory address. But why do the others write to it?

Comment: `stepi` very likely just uses `TF` to actually single-step the machine.  Since `nexti` still works when you ignore memory writes, it must do the same, but perhaps it also sets a software breakpoint on something involved in C++ exception handling, in case the instruction is a `call` that it's going to step *over*, in case the called code throws and doesn't come back to its return address.  (So maybe it's a missed optimization that it still sets this SW breakpoint even for non-call instructions where it's just going to behave like `si`)  Oh, Andrew's answer basically confirms this guess :P

Comment: You were right. Each one of these instructions has a different behavior. https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html
Thanks!

Comment: You mean `si` doesn't use range-stepping, and the others also work if you `set range-stepping off`?  That's about all the user docs have to say about the internal implementation.  I already knew the user-visible behaviour of si vs ni vs. s vs. n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_Unwind_DebugHook` symbol exists as a place for GDB (or any other debugger) to place a breakpoint and so catch exceptions.  GDB will look for this symbol (in the debug info), and it it exists, place a breakpoint there.

These breakpoints will always get inserted, even when doing something as simple as a `stepi`, just in case - you might be about to step to that address.

One problem I see with the remote trace is that GDB will be expecting an OK packet to indicate that the write succeeded, this is why you're seeing the timeout messages.

Comment: [The OP says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73576882/gdb-commands-gdbstub-to-write-to-unwind-debughook-memory-location#comment129930724_73576882) `stepi` is special and doesn't try to set a breakpoint on `_Unwind_DebugHook`.  But yeah, that makes sense that other steps, which might go more than 1 instruction, would want to catch exceptions if they happened.

Comment: @Andrew makes sense. However, `stepi` does not set a breakpoint in there though. Here's a packet dump:
```(gdb) stepi
Sending packet: $me11a00,40#85...Ack
Sending packet: $vCont?#49...Ack
Sending packet: $Hc0#db...Ack
Sending packet: $s#73...Ack
Sending packet: $g#67...Ack
Sending packet: $m141248c0,40#c4...Ack
Sending packet: $me11a00,40#85...Ack
Sending packet: $qL1200000000000000000#50...Ack

```
I tried setting a breakpoint from gdb, which caused the target to stop responding. My guess is that the stub does not have a privilege level to write into the code segment. Thanks all!